# vaadin 8 + spring custom widgetset

Tags: java, spring, maven, gwt, vaadin

i am trying to get working client-side component with class with spring+vaadin boot.

The problem is probably in custom widgetset. Where should be placed in project? close to client component? Resouces (cant compile while in resources)

But my client component is not getting called onStateChange. I have tryed everyting but i cant handle it.

```
gwt package {
client {
connector extended by AbstractExtensionConnector with @Connect directivy 
ClientSide class with java
}
AppWidgetset.gwt.xml
}

impl
{
server {
Class with AbstractExtension
}

}


pom.xml
     <plugin>
     <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
     <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
     <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1G -Xss1G</extraJvmArgs>

   <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
     <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
     <noServer>true</noServer>
     <persistentunitcachedir>${basedir}/target/tmp/gwt-unitCache</persistentunitcachedir>
     <compileReport>true</compileReport>
     <strict>true</strict>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
    <execution>
    <goals>
    <goal>update-theme</goal>
    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
    <goal>compile
    </goal> <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme 
    compilation -->
     <goal>compile-theme</goal>
     </goals>enter code here
     </execution>
     </executions>

     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You place `WidgetSet.gwt.xml` file in src/main/resources in folder that matches your widget class.

If I have my widget in

```
src/main/java/com/m1kah/vaadinapp/mywidget/MyWidget.java
```

Then my widgetset file would be in this location

```
src/main/resources/com/m1kah/vaadinapp/mywidget/Widgetset.gwl.xml
```

CSS styles and other "public" files are in same resources path in folder public.