# Specify path for generated Widgetset.gwt.xml on vaadin:update-widgetset goal

Tags: java, maven, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 project I've got a `Widgetset.gwt.xml` file in the `resources` folder structure: `src/main/resources/my/company/Plugins.gwt.xml`

From time to time, I re-generate this file with help of a Vaadin plugin for Maven:

```
mvn clean
mvn package
java -cp '.../target/.../WEB-INF/lib/*' com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler '.../src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/styles/styles.scss' '.../src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/styles/styles.css'
mvn vaadin:clean
mvn vaadin:resources
mvn vaadin:update-theme
mvn vaadin:update-widgetset
mvn vaadin:compile-theme
mvn vaadin:compile
mvn install
```

Unfortunately, `vaadin:update-widgetset` doesn't create the new file within the `resources` folder but creates a second file within the `java` folder: `src/main/java/my/company/Plugins.gwt.xml`

My Vaadin application Java class has a `@Widgetset` annotation which specifies the sub folder path: `@Widgetset("my.company.Plugins")`

I want the Vaadin plugin to overwrite my existing file in `resources` folder instead of the `java` folder.

How is this possible? Or what prevents the plugin from using the `resources` directory tree?

Comment: This one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477888/vaadin-8-spring-custom-widgetset

Comment: I've got no WidgetSet Java class file. ``Plugins.gwt.xml`` inherits ``DefaultWidgetSet`` and a couple of addons.